# Max file uploadsize

Tags: file-upload, filesize

I've the following code to upload a temp file within the server. 
I would like to check the file size. If the file is larger than 25MB I would like to abort the proces. If the file size is less than 25MB I would like to proceed with the upload.

```
   $tmp_name = $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'];
   $type = $_FILES['filename']['type'];
   $file_name = $_FILES['filename']['name'];
   $size = $_FILES['filename']['size'];
```

Anyone a suggestion?
Tnx for any reply.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something such as:

```
if($_FILES['file']['size'] > 26214400) { 
        echo "File too large. Uploaded files can be no more than 25MB.";
    } else {
... let them upload ...
```